# [gae]redirect only succeed after second time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a simple wiki on GAE, i wanted to add a normal redirect to the handler when the content put to the datastore.but it doesnt work until i submit twice it redirect to the content page not the edit page itself.

```
Here is my handler code:
class BlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        params['user'] = self.user
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class WikiFront(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, url):
        #pages = WikiData.all()
        pages = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM WikiData")
        found = False
        content = ""
        for page in pages:
            if page.url == url:
                found = True
                content = page.content
        if not found:
            self.redirect("/_edit" + url )
        else:
            self.render('wiki.html', content=content, url=url)

class EditPage(BlogHandler):

    def get(self,url):
        if self.user:
            self.render("wiki_edit.html")
        else:
            self.redirect("/login")

    def post(self,url):

        content = self.request.get('content')
        if  content:
            w = WikiData(parent = wiki_key(), content = content, url= url)
            w.put()
            self.redirect('/wiki' +  url )

    else:
        error = "Give us content plz"
        self.render("wiki_edit.html", content=content, error=error)

   # mapping stuff
   app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                           ('wiki' + PAGE_RE, WikiFront),
                           ('/_edit' + PAGE_RE, EditPage),
                           ],
                          debug=True)
```

Comment: Is the redirect problem happening on EditPage.post method? it's not very clear. Try to avoid the latitude of assumptions to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect is happening after the Post method here, add a return statement after each redirect as it's more than likely trying to finish evaluating the method without completing the redirect.